# Ember: Set model data to component value?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I tried to set a model data into an ember component data. But it didn't work.

```
actions: {
   setValue(modelData, type) {
         // this doesn't work
         this.set('currentType', type);
         this.set('currentData', modelData);
         // this also doesn't work
         this.setProperties({
             currentType: type,
             currentData: modelData
         });

   }
}
```

And got this error

[image]

Comment: Please post the rest of your component JS.

Comment: I don't have any function in this component...Wait I forgot to and one attribute...

Comment: @jrjohnson updated code

Comment: I think it would also help if we can see your component “invocation”, the template code where you use the component.